# build tables of my database MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm building tables and relation of my database.

I have a table of product and three tables of promotions with A_I ID that have differents rows according to the type of the promotion.

How I can reference from the product the correct table of promotion?

It's a little bit difficult to explain it, but I hope you will understand.
Many thanks ;))

Comment: I have built this: Product(id_product,image,...) - Promotion1(p1_id, oldPrice, newPrice, reduction, id_product) - Promotion2(p2_id, nbArticleBuy, nbArticleFree, id_product)

Answer (score 0):

You could have in your product table, a field that contains the 'promotionsTypeId', and then use just one table that is called promotion, and the promotionsTypeId will reference to the promotionId in the promotion table, instead of using 3 different tables for promotion. Also you could make promotion Generic for any Promotion.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand .. I have built this: Product(id_product,image,...) - Promotion1(p1_id, oldPrice, newPrice, reduction, id_product) - Promotion2(p2_id, nbArticleBuy, nbArticleFree, id_product)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a PromotionType table like: PrpmotionType(Id_PromotionType, TypeName)
2. Create Product table like : Product(id_product,image,...)
3. Create one promotion table instead of multiple promotion table like: 
   Promotion(Id_Promotion, Id_PromotionType, oldPrice, newPrice, reduction,   id_product)

Hope, this will help you.

Thanks